# Button Hovering Effect Working whereas Menu-Button Hovering not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw

#1f1f1f
#181818
#262626

def create_button(parent, text, command=None, side=RIGHT):
    button = Button(parent, text=text, font=("Segoe", 10), bd=0, bg="#181818", fg="white", command=command, activebackground='#3e4042', activeforeground="white")
    button.pack(side=side) return button

#Button Hovering Effect
def hover_effect(button, enter_color, leave_color):
    def on_enter(event): button['bg'] = enter_color

def on_leave(event):
    button['bg'] = leave_color

return on_enter, on_leave

def on_drag(event):
    xwin = window.winfo_x()
    event.x_root ywin = window.winfo_y()
    event.y_root window.geometry(f'+{event.x_root + xwin}+{event.y_root + ywin}')

def round_rectangle(canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, r=25, **kwargs):
    points = (x1+r, y1, x1+r, y1, x2-r, y1, x2-r, y1,
              x2, y1, x2, y1+r, x2, y1+r, x2, y2-r,
              x2, y2-r, x2, y2, x2-r, y2, x2-r, y2,
              x1+r, y2, x1+r, y2, x1, y2, x1,
              y2-r, x1, y2-r, x1, y1+r,
              x1, y1+r, x1, y1)
    return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)

#Place Holder Command
def dummy_command():
    print("This is a temporary place-holder")

def file_menu():
    round_rectangle(sidebar, 55, 0, 193, 290, fill="red")

#Window Settings
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="#1f1f1f")
window.title("Editor")
window.overrideredirect(True)

#Title Frame
title_bar = Canvas(window, bg="#181818", highlightthickness=0)
icon = Image.open('logo design.png')
resized = icon.resize((16, 16),)
picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
label = Label(title_bar, image=picture, bg="#181818")
label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18)

title_bar.pack(anchor=N, fill=X)
sidebar = Canvas(window, width=600, height=300, highlightbackground="#262626", bg="#1f1f1f")
sidebar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

#Buttons
exit_button = create_button(title_bar, '   ✕   ', window.quit)
expand_button = create_button(title_bar, '   ☐   ')
minimize_button = create_button(title_bar, '   ―   ', lambda: window.iconify() if not window.wm_state() == 'iconic' else window.deiconify())

def create_menu_button(parent, text, options, font=("Segoe", 10)):
    menu_button = Menubutton(parent, text=text, bg="#181818", fg="white", indicatoron=0, font=font)
    menu_button.menu = Menu(menu_button, tearoff=0)
    menu_button["menu"] = menu_button.menu

vars_list = [IntVar() for _ in range(len(options))]

for label, var, command in options:
    menu_button.menu.add_checkbutton(label=label, variable=var, command=command, font=font)

menu_button.pack(side='left')
return menu_button, vars_list

File Menu file_options = [("Open", IntVar(), dummy_command),
                ("Save", IntVar(), dummy_command),
                ("Exit", IntVar(), window.destroy)]

file_button, file_vars = create_menu_button(title_bar, "   File   ", file_options)

Edit Menu edit_options = [("Copy", IntVar(), dummy_command),
                ("Paste", IntVar(), dummy_command)]

edit_button, edit_vars = create_menu_button(title_bar, "   Edit   ", edit_options)

terminal_button = create_button(title_bar, '   Terminal   ', side=LEFT)
run_button = create_button(title_bar, '   Run   ', side=LEFT)

#Dragging window
def get_pos(event):
    xwin = window.winfo_x()
    ywin = window.winfo_y()
    startx = event.x_root
    starty = event.y_root
    xwin = xwin - startx
    ywin = ywin - starty

def move_window(event):
    window.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root + xwin, event.y_root + ywin))
    startx = event.x_root
    starty = event.y_root

title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
title_bar.bind('<Button-1>', get_pos)

#Button hovering effects
exit_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(exit_button, 'red', '#181818'))
exit_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(exit_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
expand_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(expand_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
expand_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(expand_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
minimize_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(minimize_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
minimize_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(minimize_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
file_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(file_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
file_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(file_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
edit_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(edit_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
edit_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(edit_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
terminal_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(terminal_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
terminal_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(terminal_button, '#181818', '#181818'))
run_button.bind('<Enter>', *hover_effect(run_button, '#3e4042', '#181818'))
run_button.bind('<Leave>', *hover_effect(run_button, '#181818', '#181818'))

Main Loop window.mainloop()
```

The Buttons have the #3e4042 colour when I hover over them, and I tried using the same function for `Menubuttons` but they're still appearing white  .

I tried using ChatGPT and it unfortunately couldn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
activebackground='#3e4042', activeforeground="white"
```

On The 10th line